# Want to push files to Azure storage with client certificates for authentication

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

I have created Azure blob storage, now i want to push files to storage for Authentication need to use client certificates.

Any Idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 5):

> I have created Azure blob storage, now i want to push files to storage
>   for Authentication need to use client certificates.

AFAIK, it is not possible to use Client Certificates as authentication/authorization mechanism for interacting with Azure Storage at least as of writing this answer.

Supported mechanisms are: Shared Key, Azure AD and Shared Access Signature based authorization. You can find more information about available authorization mechanisms here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage.

Comment: Azure AD does support using certificates for client authentication :) So OP could add the certificate on an Azure AD app, authenticate against AAD with that, and use the token to access Storage.

Comment: I am seeing this, but how can i configure in Azure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-login

Comment: As per doc need to use this command to login

>azcopy login --service-principal --certificate-path /path/to/my/cert

We can login with certs, but there is no information about the change need to to made in Azure side to accept the certs,

I Can you please provide the information regarding this ? should I export key in azure ? to access this ? then how ?

Comment: Technically speaking this is not login with certificate. Essentially here you're using a user in your Azure AD (which is of type Service Principal) and executing azcopy command as that user. Under the hoods, it is using Azure AD authentication/authorization.

Comment: Is there any way I can import the certificate issued by my organization, import this certificate to Azure and then authenticate as part of login in azcopy login ?